# Why my resolve doesn't return data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, promise

Hear is my route

```
.state('single_event',{
        url: '/event/:id',
        templateUrl: 'single_event.html',
        controller: 'singleEvent',
        resolve: {
            resolvedVal: function() {
                return 'Karl';
            }
        }

    });
```

That it my controller

```
mainApp.controller('singleEvent',['$scope', function ($scope, resolvedVal) {
    console.log(resolvedVal);
}]);
```

Why i can't get data from this resolve? I always got undefined when try to get return.
Thanks!

Comment: what is `Karl`.

Comment: perhaps `return Promise.resolve('Karl');` or `return $q.when('Karl')` - I think you need to return an actual Promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't injected the resolve variable correctly. You are using 'square-brackets' notation to inject dependecies, which we use to uglify code but you are not passing `resolvedVal` in it. So thats why you are getting undefined.

Here's the updated code, it will work.

```
mainApp.controller('singleEvent',['$scope', 'resolvedVal', function ($scope, resolvedVal) {
    console.log(resolvedVal);
}]);
```

Let me know if it doesn't solve your issue.

For more on how to inject dependencies inside 'square-brackets' inside controllers, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33188212/6563812)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't solve my issue. The problem was in setting up controller through the 'ng-controller' in my html and defining controller in my route. It makes some conflicts. But your answer was very helpful in another question. Thanks !!!